Mobile Application : Migration from Xamarin to Net8.0 : Cleartext communication not enabled
I have to migrate a Xamarin/C# application to net8.0 because of Xamarin end of support. I am not a specialist of C#, .NET technologies, and I have just made a few modifications in this application and I have no colleagues to help me. I am using Visual Studio 17.9.6
When I call var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resource); I have the error :

CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client

I have done like other subject say :
Here is the manifest file :
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.mci.mvision" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="30" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

Here is the main class :
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan | SoftInput.StateHidden)]
public class MVision : AppCompatActivity

Here is the security config file :
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
      <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>

To conclude, this project worked very well when it was in Xamarin, but the error occurs in .Net8.0 .
Have you any idea ?

Does this answer your question? Trust additional CAs and make use of the Android certificate store in a net6 MAUI solution

Thank you, but it does not answer my question. First I do not have any certificate in my application. Then I do all the action described in the links. (security-config, usesCleartextTraffic="true", etc)

Have you checked out Gerald's sample repository that is linked in one of the answers under that question? If that works for you, you should be able to figure out what's different in your setup.

The 2 main differences is that he uses a MauiApplication whereas I use a AppCompatActivity and he uses a Maui framework, and I use a Net8.0 framework.

Ah, I was under the assumption that you're migrating from XF to MAUI. My bad.

After testing, this is working fine on MAUI. The problem seems to come from .NET8

Removing package modernhttpclient-updated (2.8.0) and adding package modernhttpclient (2.4.2) solved my problem.
Best regards.
Christophe
